# Accessing data with iloc or other method for more than one item using loop in it

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hello to all fellow members,

so what I'm doing in my project is through an API I'm accessing stock price of 10 scripts and I'm sending these tick data to mysql. From mysql I'm retreiving the data back to calculate or to use resample the stock price in OHLC format, well following is the code for using the resample function:

```
def data_from_sql(): # fetch all query
try:
    db = pymysql.connect(host, user, password, database)
    cursor = db.cursor()

    sql_query_2 = "SELECT * FROM tick_data.ticks WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE"

    cursor.execute(sql_query_2)

    records = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print("Total rows are: ", len(records))
    df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['token', 'last_price', 'time']).set_index('time')
    ohlc = df.groupby('token').resample('5min')['last_price'].ohlc()

    excel_details(ohlc) # send the data to other function for updating my excel sheet.

except pymysql.Error as error:
    print("Failed to read data from table", error)

data_from_sql()

while True:
data_from_sql()  # for infinite loop
```

Ok now the output of the above code is:

[image]

Now, what I need is: for each token number I need "close" price of the previous timeframe, i.e 5 minute before the current timeframe, for eg for token number "5633" I need "close" price at 2020-03-12 14:15:00 not of 2020-03-12 14:20:00, since "2020-03-12 14:20:00" candle or time is not closed and would like to update my excel sheet for the same.

So for above result I'm coding as:

```
new_close = ohlc.iloc[-2]['close']
    print(new_close)
```

And for this I'm getting the *close_price of only my last token* no "3861249":

# output is:

```
292.05
```

But I need close_price of all the token number, so please help me out on how to get the desired result.

And also if possible can anyone tell me how to improve the perfomance of my code? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ciao tanjiro,

what I would do is the following. If you can manage to adapt to your case the first part (date extraction), you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dateformat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
#the following isolate the date 
#now_date = datetime.now() (or something like this)
now_date = datetime.strptime("2020-03-12 14:20:00",dateformat)
dt = timedelta(minutes=5)
prev_date = now-dt
prev = prev_date.strftime(dateformat)

#the following gets the wanted values
#1. select the subdatabase
prev_ohlc = ohlc[ohlc['time']==prev]
#2. get the values
new_close = prev_ohlc['close'].values
```